# Ant design overrides react emotion rules

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, antd, emotion

In my project I use Ant design components along with react-emotion.
I am ending up with the situation when sometimes ant design styles are added after emotion styles within page `<head>`tag like.

```html
...
<style data-emotion="css">...</style>
<style>...</style> <-- ant design style -->
...
```

`Antd` is  added to `create react app` via `customize-cra` package as

```js
module.exports = override(
  addDecoratorsLegacy(),
  fixBabelImports("import", {
    libraryName: "antd",
    libraryDirectory: 'es',
    style: true
  }),
  addLessLoader({
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    modifyVars: darkTheme.default
  }),
  ...addBabelPlugins(
    "polished",

    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? 'emotion'
    : ['emotion', { sourceMap: true }]
  )
);
```

This is the reason emotion styles are overridden by antd styles.
Anyone has an idea how to fix this?
I would prefer not to add `antd` compiled css styles.